# Splitting a string separated by "\r\n" into a list of lines?

Tags: python, string

I am reading in some data from the subprocess module's communicate method.  It is coming in as a large string separated by "\r\n"s.  I want to split this into a list of lines.  How is this performed in python?

Comment: When you read up on `string.split()` what did you find?  What have you tried?  What tutorial are you using?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the splitlines method on the string.

From the docs:

> **str.splitlines([keepends])**
>       Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries.
>   Line breaks are not included in the
>   resulting list unless keepends is
>   given and true.

This will do the right thing whether the line endings are "\r\n", "\r" or "\n" regardless of the OS.

NB a line ending of "\n\r" will also split, but you will get an empty string between each line since it will consider "\n" as a valid line ending and "\r" as the ending of the next line. e.g.

```
>>> "foo\n\rbar".splitlines()
['foo', '', 'bar']
```

Comment: Note that "foo\r\nbar".splitlines() returns ['foo', 'bar']. CRLF/CR/LF are all recognized but LFCR is seen as 2 lines.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the doc for string methods.  In particular the split method.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods

Answer (score 1):

```
s = re.split(r"[~\r\n]+", string_to_split)
```

This will give you a list of strings in s.

Comment: Although, if you think `'a\n\nb'` should be split into three strings (`'a'`, `''`, and `'b'`), this will fail.

Comment: That's true, this will ignore blank lines.